# How does one pass a variable from template tool kit file to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, perl, templates

I am working in web based project which is developed in PERL, HTML, JAVASCRIPT and TEMPLATE TOOL KIT. we are using mysql as the back end.

we fetch values from a specific table to a hash structure in Perl. Using the value  from that structure, we process the template files which also include the JavaScript content.

For Ex: say hash{i}=5;
in template toolkit file (.tmpl file):

```
[%  IF i == 5 %] 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="[% js_link('five.js') %]"></script> [% END %]
[%  IF i == 10 %] 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="[% js_link('ten.js') %]"></script>  [% END %]
```

Now the problem, I have a situation where i have to use "i" value inside the JS file to switch between the code, removing sourcing of multiple files.

```
[%  IF i %] 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="[% js_link('common.js') %]"></script> [% END %]
```

Inside JavaScript file:

```
if( i == 5) {
lang_array['i'] = 'FIVE';
 }else if( i == 10) {
lang_array['i'] = 'TEN';
 }
 // using the above array some more calculation follows
```

I tried saving a hidden variable in the template file then trying to access the variable by getElementByName, but not successful.

So can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.
Please help me.

Comment: That is really oldschool style. You should stricly separate your perl and javascript code if possible. Use JSON to pass data and communicate between server & client.

Answer (score 6):

Define it as a javascript variable before you load your script:

```
[% IF i %]
var i = [% i %];
[% END %]
```

Now all your scripts can access it as a global variable. (I'd suggest you name it something more descriptive though)

Comment: Hey Cfreak,                                                   thanks for the speedy reply.                                       I am little confused with the answer :(                                                                                                                                      [% IF user.lang_pref %]
<script type="text/javascript">
var lang_pref = [% user.lang_pref %];
</script>
[%END%]                                                                  
"Message: 'lang_pref' is undefined" is the JavaScript error message that i am getting in IE

Comment: Ok you probably need to have an else in the template syntax that defines it as false. That way when it's used IE won't complain that it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

var ttVars = {};

ttVars.i = [% i %] || 0;